# How can I quickly seal wet pressure-treated plywood?

Tags: plywood, pressure-treated

I am replacing the floor in my camper and want to use 3/4" pressure-treated plywood but I want to apply some water sealer before I lay it down. Is there a way I can do this without waiting a lengthy amount of time for the plywood to dry out?

Comment: Have you considered putting down housewrap underneath instead? Something that breathes might be better, and you don't have to wait.

Comment: @isherwood I am concerned about putting anything down that might get a hole in it and trapping water between the product and the wood

Comment: Housewrap doesn't do that.

Comment: See if a lumber yard near you sells KDAT Plywood. Kiln Dried After Treatment.   If so it’s worth the extra money especially on a small project.  You could use a quality exterior sealer on the underside before installation. Sealing wet plywood is problem.  Either it does no good because surface rejects it or it locks moisture in that would escape through the underside had it not been sealed.

Comment: @Kris I have looked online but haven’t found any yet.

Comment: What part of the planet do you live on?

Comment: I live near Saginaw Michigan.  I looked through all the big box stores and they didnt have any that was KDAT

Comment: Why in the world would you ever pay for KD plywood? Plywood is made by cutting sheets of veneer , then it is dried, then it is assembled with the glue and put in a hot press until the glue is dry. In other words plywood is dry unless it has been sitting out in the rain   The reason so many plywood plants burn down is they are working with the best kindling there is add sanding and the dry wood dust makes great fires.  Been through that at swansons Springfield ~5 years ago.

Comment: @EdBeal it’s pressure treated plywood and because of that it is fairly wet when you get it

Comment: I guess that is one type Of plywood I have never seen or used, I would just use sanded and plugged for a floor or the blows may show. Don’t waste $ on marine basically that is just a higher grade of veneer with the same glue. I would use caution with anything not sanded and plugged for a floor because that will show thru vinyl.